# Codeigniter routing, setting custom controllers directory based on a session userdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

Is there any way to route in CI based on session data.

For example:

```
CI
 |-controllers
 |       |------student
 |       |         |--dashboard.php
 |       |         |--marks.php
 |       |
 |       |------teacher
 |       |         |--dashboard.php
 |       |         |--marks.php
 |...
```

so that

`if ($this->session->userdata('type') == 'student')`

`http://localhost/CI/dashboard` will route at controllers/student/dashboard

```
else if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'teacher')
```

`http://localhost/CI/dashboard` will route at controllers/teacher/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

If the folder structure is going to be exactly same (as you described in Q), and you do not require user to see what section he is in (either **teacher**/dashboard, **student**/dashboard), there is no need for any routing at all.

Use the logic you provided and simply load different views

eg. make function

```
function _render( $view_file = 'dashboard', $data ) {

    if ($this->session->userdata('type') == 'student') {
        $this->load->view('/student/'. $view_file, $data);
    } else {
        $this->load->view('/teacher/'. $view_file, $data);
    }

}
```

*note: with aproach above your controller is going to be huge in length because you would have to have functions for both teacher/student, aproach above just differentiate view files*

If you want to make sure that your URL looks like /teacher/dashboard... and student/dashboard

I would go for this aproach

extend CI_Controller with this [tutorial](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY).

and in constructor make sure you redirect where you want to <strike>go</strike> redirect something like

(in **MY_Controller.php**)

```
function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    if ($this->uri->segment(1) === FALSE) {//segment 'teacher' or 'student' doesnt exists
        if ($this->session->userdata('type') == 'student') {
            redirect('/student/dashboard');
        } else if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'teacher') {
            redirect('/teacher/dashboard');
        } else {
           //default action
        }

    } else {

        if ($this->uri->segment(1) != $this->session->userdata('type')) {
        //something is not right, session do not match the segment
        //logout or redirect to right segment
            redirect($this->session->userdata('type').'/dashboard');
        }
        //else is not needed code continues no redirects are needed
    }

}
```